# Nodejs request module - how can I cancel the request?

Tags: node.js, module, request

I'm using the well know request module (https://github.com/request/request) that request some page and then I made some calculations and built the response code for user.

The thing is, that sometimes I receive the correct code (200) but the data (some kind of security measure?) is sending FOREVER - request won't stop. How can I kill it after some time of "inactivity"?

```
var requestOptions =
{
    url : url,
    timeout : 10000, //// here we set the request timeout - 10 seconds
    headers : {'we can also set some headers' : 'sometimes the pages require a headers - there is no proper responce without those'}
};

var ourRequest = request(requestOptions, function(err, resp, body)
{
    if (err || resp.statusCode >= 400) // OR just - (err || resp.statusCode !== 200)
    {
        console.log(err.connect);
        if (resp)
        {
            console.log('ERROR at last there is response (code: ' + resp.statusCode + ')\n');
        }
        else
        {
            if ((err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') && (err.connect === true))
            {
                //// when there's a timeout and connect is true, we're meeting the conditions described for the timeout option where the OS governs
                console.log('REQUEST TIMEOUT - SYSTEM FAULT!');
            }
            else if ((err.code === 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT') || (err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT'))
            {
                console.log('REQUEST TIMEOUT - NODE EXPRESS/REQUEST FAULT!');
            }
            console.log('ERROR you cant ge the body of the page...');
        }
    }
    if (resp.statusCode >= 300 && resp.statusCode < 400)
    {
        console.log('page REDIRECT');
    }
    if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200)
    {
        console.log('ok, we get the body, lets do something with it');
        console.log('some async code example to send part of the data to other servers, etc.');
    }
});
```

It's a internal server when I get the data from - it sometimes online, and sometimes completely offline so I discover that some pages have a similar "functionalities" like for example validator. As a url set up some page and add '`https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=`' before it, make few requests to see that sometimes it hang up, and timeout is not working on them (probably cause the receive correct status code).

How can I kill the request, after 10 seconds, even if it receive proper status code? Thanks for any thoughts on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

resp.request.abort();